# how to log data into excel in java logging

Tags: java, logging

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
    FileHandler fh;  

    try {  

        // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
        fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

        // the following statement is used to log any messages  
        logger.info("My first log");  

    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    logger.info("Test1 : Hi How r u?");  

}
```

Produces the output at `MyLogFile.log`

```
Apr 2, 2013 9:57:08 AM testing.MyLogger main  
INFO: My first log  
Apr 2, 2013 9:57:08 AM testing.MyLogger main  
INFO: Test : Hi How r u?
```

Here `MyLogFile.log` is text file , I want to create excel file for output instead of text , please suggest something on this ?
I want to output in excel columnwise/rowwise like below -

```
column1   column2
Test      Hi How r u ? ......
```

I am using Apache POI to read from Excel input , creating log using below - import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter; 
and want to print log output in excel instead of text file.
csv output file as a test case execution report apart from log file
excel report file apart from log file.

Comment: Maybe use `.xlsx` rather than `.log`, there is some lib to write in an excel file, or without lib, write a `csv` file with comma

Comment: What is `java logging`? Do oyu mean JCL, log4j, ...?

Comment: @Jens I am using Apache POI to read from Excel input , creating log using below - import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter; and want to print output log in excel instead of text file.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need a specific [`Handler`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/handlers.html) writing to Excel files instead of a simple `FileHandler`.

Well I haven't found any existing one but you can [create your own](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/logging/custom-handler.html) quite easily since you already use POI in your project.

Comment: I m not using maven , I am using only apache poi , given example is using maven

Comment: how to create using apache poi libs and java only ?

Comment: @priya Maven is "only" the build and dependency management.... tool. It will not change anything for you since you already have integrated POI. Just ignore the example project uses Maven. You should give it a try however (or to a similar tool such as gradle).